# How to calculate the general term formula of $t(k)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, exact-sequence

I am trying to find general formula of the sequence $t(k)$ defined by:

$t(1)=2,t(2)=8,g(1)=2,g(2)=4$

and

$t(k+1)=t(k) \cdot2^{g(k)}$,

$g(k)=\dfrac{t(k)}{g(k-1)}$.

alternatively, I want to know if $t(k)$ is bounded by exponential size of $k$.